# Как прочитать ответ API postcalc?

Tags: php, кодировка, curl

Пишу php скрипт с запросом curl к [api](http://www.postcalc.ru/api.html) для того, чтобы получить стоимость доставки.

Вот функция:

```
function methodCurl($to,$weight,$price) {   

    $baseUrl = "http://api.postcalc.ru/?";
    $baseUrl .= $this->indexFrom;

        if(!empty($to)){
            $to = rawurlencode ($to);
            $baseUrl .= "&t=".$to;  
        }
        if(!empty($weight)){
            $baseUrl .= "&w=".$weight;
        }

    $baseUrl .= $this->country;
    $baseUrl .= "&o=php";
    echo $baseUrl . "<br>";
    $ch = curl_init($baseUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_errno($ch);

    $info['result'] = $result;
    $info['error'] = $err;
    $info['errormsg'] = $errmsg;
        if($info['http_code'] == 200){
            echo mb_detect_encoding($info['result']) . "</br>";
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($info);
            echo "</pre>";

        }

}
```

И все вроде бы хорошо, запрос формируется верно (если полученный запрос вставить в браузер - все нормально открывается), но при выводе результата через скрипт - выводится хрень:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кодировку проверил везде - utf-8. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: не пойму что выводит echo mb_detect_encoding($info['result']) . "</br>"; ?

Comment: Это проверка кодировки, выводит UTF-8

Comment: Покажите заголовки. Возможно, принудительно прилетает сжатый текст, хоть вы и не запрашивали его. Но раз браузер воспринимает нормально, то об этом должно быть сказано в заголовках ответа.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 04 Jul 2016 08:59:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u2
Content-Encoding: gzip
PostcalcServer: 88.198.243.244
X-Cache-Status: MISS

Answer (score 1):

Угадал. Читайте внимательнее документацию, ссылку на которую вы сами дали в вопросе:

> Ответ сервера Postcalc.RU всегда архивируется в gzip

И парой предложений далее описано как с этим жить дальше и даже описано несколько возможных граблей

```
// Добавляем распаковку:
if ( substr($Response,0,3) == "\x1f\x8b\x08" ) $Response=gzinflate(substr($Response,10,-8));
```